# unmarshall the date object in xml

Tags: java, jaxb

when unmarshalling from xml, can we map the date object or calendar object?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about JAXB here?  If so then yes. Just use the javaType binding declaration in your JAXB bindings.  See here: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbbf.html

Comment: Also see this other stackoverflow question and its solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679266/simple-conversion-between-java-util-date-and-xmlgregoriancalendar

Answer (score 1):

Yes. According to the mapping table on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding), xsd:date maps to [XMLGregorianCalendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can map to Calendar, Date, or XMLGregorianCalendar:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/01/jaxb-and-datetime-properties.html

You can leverage the @XmlSchemaType annotation to choose the XML format:  xsd:date, xsd:dateTime, xsd:time, etc.