# Dozer mapping of java.lang.Date (as a Map field) to XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, date, dictionary, dozer

I have an xml mapping defined:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>java.util.HashMap</class-a>
    <class-b>com.example.MyClass</class-b>
    <field>
        <a key=&quot;myDateField&quot;>this</a>
        <b>myXMLGregorianCalendarField</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Here value for key `myDateField` contains instance of `java.lang.Date class`.
Field `com.example.MyClass#myXMLGregorianCalendarField` expects instance of `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`.

This mapping always throws an exception:

```
MapId: null
Type: null
Source parent class: java.util.HashMap
Source field name: this
Source field type: class java.util.Date
Source field value: Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 MSK 1970
Dest parent class: com.example.MyClass
Dest field name: myXMLGregorianCalendarField
Dest field type: javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar
org.dozer.MappingException: Illegal object type for the method 'setMyXMLGregorianCalendarField'. 
Expected types: 
    javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar
Actual types: 
    java.util.Date
```

**How to make this conversion work properly?**

**Note**
Long-long debugging revealed that primitive converters are called differently for maps and "non-maps". So here comes the second question: **why?**

Comment: Are you saying that the conversion works when the `Date` is not a Map field?

Comment: Yep, u got it right. The conversion works just fine when `Date` is not a `Map` field.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean in the last section but you can try using a custom setter in the destination class to perform this mapping.

Your mapping file would look like this:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>java.util.HashMap</class-a>
    <class-b>com.example.MyClass</class-b>
    <field>
        <a key="myDateField">this</a>
        <b set-method="setMyXMLGregorianCalendarField(java.util.Date)">myXMLGregorianCalendarField</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Implement the custom setter in `MyClass`, perhaps using a conversion like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679266/simple-conversion-between-java-util-date-and-xmlgregoriancalendar).

Comment: **1)** There is no method `com.example.MyClass#setMyXMLGregorianCalendarField(java.util.Date)` available. Only `com.example.MyClass#setMyXMLGregorianCalendarField(javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar)` exists. **2)** Dozer is shipped with `XMLGregorianCalendarConverter` which works fine if source object (defined by `<class-a>` tag) is **not** any instance of `Map`

Comment: I assumed that `MyClass` is your class. Your other option is to implement a custom converter extending the `DozerConverter` class as described [here](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html)

Comment: Of course implementing another custom converter is an easiest (and the most obvious) way to make this conversion, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Dozer already has such converter built-in, so I want to reuse it. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: I agree. It's a shame that the `XMLGregorianCalendarConverter` doesn't extend the `DozerConverter` class for such cases. Please accept my answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the hint tag to implicitely convert from date to gregorian.

Here s a sample code:

```
    <field>  
       <a key="myDateField">this</a>
       <b>myXMLGregorianCalendarField</b>
       <a-hint>java.util.GregorianCalendar</a-hint>
   </field>
```

I don't know whether dozer the implicit type conversion or not , but if it does , then you don't need to write any exta custom convertor method.
In case , it does not perform an implicite conversion, try custom getter or setter method.
in which perform the date to GregorianCalendar conversion. 
See this for custom getter and setter methods : [custom getter-setter](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/custommethods.html)

Comment: I checked it recently. It does implicite conversion for date to xmlgregoriancalander. So i think ,you want required any custom converter.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I found the answer here,
[Automatic conversion in dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/simpleproperty.html)

Under this,look at third last option in Data type conversion heading. They wrote these can be mapped internally without any custom convertor help : java.util.Date, java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time, java.sql.Timestamp, java.util.Calendar, java.util.GregorianCalendar