# How to Convert a UNIX time stamp to XMLGregorianCalendar value in java?

Tags: java, date

How to Convert a UNIX time stamp to XMLGregorianCalendar value in java ?

**TIME STAMP: 1379487623**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple conversion between java.util.Date and XMLGregorianCalendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679266/simple-conversion-between-java-util-date-and-xmlgregoriancalendar)

Answer (score 4):

```
long time = 1379487623;
Date date = new Date((long)time*1000);
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(date);
XMLGregorianCalendar date2 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
```

Comment: The unix time is in seconds, not milliseconds `1379487623 != 1379487623000` - AFAIK ;)

Comment: Yes, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371326/java-date-from-unix-timestamp