# How to enter date/time for the datatype XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, datetime, set

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java.util.Date to XMLGregorianCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835889/java-util-date-to-xmlgregoriancalendar)

I have a Java method with a parameter from the type XMLGregorianCalendar, but I don't know how to set Date/Time:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar startDateTime = ???
```

Thank you very much, for helping...

Comment: Did you look at all the various `set` methods? (`setYear` etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
// ...
XMLGregorianCalendar xc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(
    int year,
    int month,
    int day,
    int hour,
    int minute,
    int second,
    int millisecond,
    int timezone)
```

there are other versions of `newXMLGregorianCalendar()`, eg `newXMLGregorianCalendar(GregorianCalendar cal)`.

Comment: I don't understand: int timezone ??

Comment: timezone - offset in minutes. DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED indicates optional field is not set.   See javadoc, there are many options

Comment: it is not time, it is a calendar, when you say eg 2012-01-01 12:00 the question is what is the timezone?