# convert java.sql.Timestamp to javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar without losing nanos

Tags: java

What's the cleanest way to convert `java.sql.Timestamp` to `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`?

Given that `XMLGregorianCalendar` has `BigDecimal` precision for fractional seconds there's no loss of precision, however I'm not sure what time zone I should set at the `XMLGregorianCalendar` object given that `java.sql.Timestamp` is time-zone independent.

There is an answer on SO on [how to convert `java.util.Date` to `XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/835889/274677) so I could cast my `Timestamp` to `java.util.Date` but that would lead to loss of precision in the sub-millisecond range which is unnecessary as the target datatype (`XMLGregorianCalendar`) can hold the nanoseconds component of the source datatype (`Timestamp`).

Answer (score 5):

I'm doing this way:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

public class ApiRuntime {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
        ts.setNanos(123456789);

        LocalDateTime ldt = ts.toLocalDateTime();

        XMLGregorianCalendar cal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();

        cal.setYear(ldt.getYear());
        cal.setMonth(ldt.getMonthValue());
        cal.setDay(ldt.getDayOfMonth());
        cal.setHour(ldt.getHour());
        cal.setMinute(ldt.getMinute());
        cal.setSecond(ldt.getSecond());
        cal.setFractionalSecond(new BigDecimal("0." + ldt.getNano()));

        System.out.println("Timestamp::" + ts);
        System.out.println("Calendar:::" + cal);
    }
}
```

That example outputs:

```
Timestamp::2015-08-25 20:59:35.123456789  
Calendar:::2015-08-25T20:59:35.123456789
```

Answer (score 1):

`java.sql.Timestamp` holds the number of millis since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT/UTC + nanos. Hence, unless you're doing anything daft in between I suggest that [based on the XMLGregorianCalendar docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#datetimefield-timezone) you set the timezone to 0 (UTC).

Answer (score 1):

[AlexCG answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32211975/5802539) is working not quite properly for some cases (when we give less than 9 digits number in nanos)e.g. when we set nanos to 25 then we receive output like this:

```
Timestamp::2020-01-02 16:30:01.000000025
Calendar:::2020-01-02T16:30:01.25
```

which is not true.
I modified a little this method, now it's:

```
    @Test
    public void convertLocalDataTimeToXmlGCal() throws Exception {

        Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
        ts.setNanos(25);

        LocalDateTime ldt = ts.toLocalDateTime();

        XMLGregorianCalendar cal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();

        cal.setYear(ldt.getYear());
        cal.setMonth(ldt.getMonthValue());
        cal.setDay(ldt.getDayOfMonth());
        cal.setHour(ldt.getHour());
        cal.setMinute(ldt.getMinute());
        cal.setSecond(ldt.getSecond());
        String nanos = "0." + StringUtils.leftPad(String.valueOf(ldt.getNano()), 9, '0');
        cal.setFractionalSecond(new BigDecimal(nanos));

        System.out.println("Timestamp::" + ts);
        System.out.println("Calendar:::" + cal);
    }
```

now the output is correct:

```
Timestamp::2020-01-02 16:33:02.000000025
Calendar:::2020-01-02T16:33:02.000000025
```

Apache Commons library is required.