# Converting LocalDate to GregorianCalendar in Java

Tags: java, jodatime, gregorian-calendar

I want to convert `LocalDate` to `GregorianCalendar`. Please advice.

In my application we are using `GregorianCalendar` to work with date's. But I got a Joda `LocalDate` as a return type when I called one of the webservice.
Now I want to convert that `LocalDate` to `GregorianCalendar` as it's differing with the month value display. Please see the sample code below.

`LocalDate` displays 10 for the month October whereas `GregorianCalendar` display 9 for the month October as it starts from index 0. Please suggest how to convert `LocalDate` to `GregorianCalendar`, I tried to see API methods but with no luck.

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

// Sample code below
LocalDate localDateObj = new LocalDate();
System.out.println("Month value using LocalDate :" + localDateObj.getMonthOfYear());
System.out.println("Date using LocalDate : " + localDateObj);

// Converting LocalDate to DateTime
DateTime dateTimeObj = localDateObj.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay();
System.out.println("DateTime month " + dateTimeObj.getMonthOfYear());
System.out.println("Date using DateTime : " + dateTimeObj);

// GregorianCalendar
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
System.out.println("Month value using GregorianCalendar:" + gc.OCTOBER);
System.out.println("GC :" + gc.getTime());
```

#### Output:

> ```
> Month value using LocalDate :10
> Date using LocalDate : 2016-10-13
> DateTime month 10
> Date using DateTime : 2016-10-13T00:00:00.000-04:00
> Month value using GregorianCalendar:9
> GC :Thu Oct 13 16:14:43 EDT 2016
> ```

Comment: Can you use `gregorianCalendar.setDate(localDate.toDate())`?

Comment: @msandiford - GregorianCalendar does not have setDate(..) method, cannot do that

Comment: My apologies, typo at the last minute.  I meant `gregorianCalendar.setTime(localDate.toDate())`.  Despite the name, this actually sets the date as well.

Comment: @msandiford - LocalDate doesn't have toDate() method..facing hard time to solve this issue..

Comment: OK, well I'm using Joda Time 2.7, and the documentation tells me that the `toDate()` method has been available since version 2.0.  I presume you must be using an older version.  Which version?

Comment: @msandiford - joda-time1.6.jar is the jar I'm using. I tried using gregorianCalendar.setTime(jodaLocalDateObj.toDate()) and its showing error - The method toDate() is not undefined for the type LocalDate.

Comment: OK, then can you use `gregorianCalendar.setTimeInMillis(dateTime.getMillis())`?  Note the change to using `DateTime` rather than `LocalDate` - I think this should work in Joda Time 1.6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert between LocalDate and XMLGregorianCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767084/convert-between-localdate-and-xmlgregoriancalendar)

Answer (score 21):

Try this example to convert `LocalDate` to `GregorianCalendar`

```
LocalDate localDateObj = LocalDate.now();
GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from(localDateObj.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
```

Note: `gc.OCTOBER` is set to 9 but it is indicating the tenth month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars.

Hope this help!

Comment: I am using java5, ZoneId class does not support. Please suggest the same when using java5. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Either you can map date manually:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar.Builder()
.setDate(date.getYear(), date.getMonthOfYear(), date.getDayOfMonth())
.build();
```

Comment: Note that you'll need to cast it as `build()` returns a `Calendar` type

Comment: In addition to @Andy 's comment, it is also worth noticing that the above example is using `LocalDate` from the [`Joda-Time`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) library, i.e. **not** the Java's own Date and Time library, which also have [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class. The method `getMonthOfYear()` is only present in Joda-Time, in the Java's own equivalent it would be `getMonthValue()`.