# Set XMLGregorianCalendar value from a Calendar date in Java

Tags: java, date, calendar, xmlgregoriancalendar

what is the best way to set a XMLGregorianCalendar value from a Calendar date?

```
    posting.setXMLGregorianCalendar(message.getCreateDate());
```

here my class:

```
Message.java

private Calendar createDate;
public Calendar getCreateDate() {
    return createDate;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. You may also consider if you can do without `XMLGregorianCalendar` since it is old too. Instead use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out this:

```
Calendar createDate = Calendar.getInstance();
Date cDate = createDate.getTime();
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(cDate);
XMLGregorianCalendar date2 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error at newInstance() "  XMLGregorianCalendar date2 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
"

Comment: I needed to add try-catch too, Thanks a lot !

Comment: Lol.. Yeah need to add try-catch :) :)

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar( 
    GregorianCalendar.from( 
        ZonedDateTime.now( 
            ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) 
        ) 
    )
)
```

## A moment requires a time zone

The [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html), [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html), and [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html) classes all represent a moment, that is, a date, a time-of-day, and an assigned time zone. Stay aware of the issue of time zone. If you fail to address zone explicitly, the JVM’s current default time zone will be assigned implicitly.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Edmonton`, `Africa/Tunis`, or `Europe/Moscow`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

## *java.time*

These `…Calendar` classes are also *terrible*. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community gave up on them years ago with the adoption of JSR 310… and so should you. Use only the *java.time* classes for your business logic.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;   // Capture the current moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
```

## Convert

If interacting with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert between legacy classes and modern classes. Look to new methods added to the old classes.

A `ZonedDateTime` object can be converted to a `GregorianCalendar` object (a subclass of `Calendar`) by calling [`GregorianCalendar.from( ZonedDateTime )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#from(java.time.ZonedDateTime)).

```
GregorianCalendar gregCal = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

A `GregorianCalendar` can be converted to a `XMLGregorianCalendar`, but we have to go to one extra step. The `XMLGregorianCalendar` class itself lacks a converter method from `GregorianCalendar`. A helper class can get the job done, [`DatatypeFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html), as shown in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29770443/642706) by [Stephen Colebourne, “JodaStephen”](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen), the inventor of *java.time*.

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar( gregCal );
```

Not that I recommend it, but you can combine this into a one-liner as seen in the *tl;dr* section up top.

[image]