# Cannot format to XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, xml, spring, datetime, xsd

I convert from String date to XMLGregorianCalendar

```
public static void convertStringToXMLDate(String dateString) {
    Date dob=null;
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    try {
        dob=df.parse( "20140210" );
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

    cal.setTime(dob);
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate3;
    try {
        xmlDate3 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),dob.getHours(),dob.getMinutes(),dob.getSeconds(),DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
        System.out.println(xmlDate3);
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This code print xmlDate3 = 2014-02-10T00:00:00.

How can I format this to 20140210 or 2014/02/10 in XMLGregorianCalendar

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835889/java-util-date-to-xmlgregoriancalendar, since OP already know how to convert `Date` to `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. The [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) is a (from javadoc):

> Representation for W3C XML Schema 1.0 date/time datatypes [...] normatively defined in [W3C XML Schema 1.0 Part 2, Section 3.2.7-14](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime).

As you can see, the referenced normative definition of a **dateTime** is:

> *3.2.7.1 Lexical representation*
>
> The [·lexical space·](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-lexical-space) of **dateTime** consists of finite-length sequences of characters of the form: `'-'? yyyy '-' mm '-' dd 'T' hh ':' mm ':' ss ('.' s+)? (zzzzzz)?`

The only potential choice in format is between "Lexical representation" and "Canonical representation". Formatting like you show (`20140210` and `2014/02/10`) is not valid for an XML Schema defined **dateTime** value.

---

Now, if you actually wanted an XML **date** value, not a **dateTime**, then you should call [`newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(int year, int month, int day, int timezone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newXMLGregorianCalendarDate%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) instead of [`newXMLGregorianCalendar(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond, int timezone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newXMLGregorianCalendar%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

The output will then be:

```
2014-02-10
```

Comment: Thank for your answer! It is helpful for me