# convert 'java.sql.Date' to class 'javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar'

Tags: java, datetime, xmlgregoriancalendar

I have a scenario where I have to convert `java.sql.Date` to class `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar` and I tried the following

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(financialTransactionProcessDataObj.invReceivedDate);
DatatypeFactory dTF = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
XMLGregorianCalendar date = dTF.newXMLGregorianCalendar(cal);
```

I am getting

`java.lang.SecurityException: Restricted method invocation.` for DatatypeFactory

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835889/java-util-date-to-xmlgregoriancalendar.

Comment: It seems that your code is correct.
I suppose that the problem is related to financialTransactionProcessDataObj.invReceivedDate. Can you check if replacing it with new java.util.Date() it works?

Comment: @user2612030 I know its a duplicate but I am seeing the java.lang.SecurityException: Restricted method invocation. for DatatypeFactory, so is there any other way to do this

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO no it didnt I am seeing java.lang.SecurityException: Restricted method invocation. for DatatypeFactory for the script I am writing, so I just wanted to know is there any other way

Comment: IN what environment are you working? (tomcat? jboss? jar standalone? something different?)

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO something different.

Comment: Try to search for specific security restrictions related to your environment. Or post informations related to it to see if somebody can help you here.

Comment: @user2612030 What is the difference between the accepted answer to the question you are linking to compared to the code in this question? I cannot see how that question would help.

Comment: Siva, you may want to post a complete stack trace.

Comment: You may not need an `XMLGregorianCalendar`. If this is for formatting your date for use in XML, what you need is ISO 8601 format, and the classes of [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) produce that format through their `toString` methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.Date to XMLGregorianCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835889/java-util-date-to-xmlgregoriancalendar)

Comment: My 0.02 cents: This question is not a duplicate since the OP is already trying what it suggests in the answers to the linked question, so those answer won’t help any further. And not all errors can be readily reproduced everywhere. Asking about them is still OK and not a reason to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your desired result is an `XMLGregorianCalendar` like `2018-06-30T00:00:00.000+02:00` (at least that’s the result I get when running your code on my computer (it works)).

This answer further assumes that you are getting your `java.sql.Date` from an SQL database and that you want your `XMLGregorianCalendar` for the `String` that you get from its `toXMLFormat` method. If so, I suggest that you neither need `java.sql.Date` nor `XMLGregorianCalendar` (that’s right).

To get your date from your result set:

```
    LocalDate invReceivedDate = yourResultSet.getObject("inv_receive_date", LocalDate.class);
```

I haven’t tested the code, and you should of course substitute the correct column label instead of `inv_receive_date`. If using JPA a modern version can give you a `LocalDate` object too.

To get your string for XML:

```
    OffsetDateTime date = invReceivedDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toOffsetDateTime();
    System.out.println(date.toString());
```

In my test run this printed

```
2018-06-30T00:00+02:00
```

If you compare with the string I got from `date.toXMLFormat()` before, you will notice that the seconds and fraction of second are not printed. This is probably OK. The format is ISO 8601, and according to that standard seconds and fraction of second are optional, so leaving them out when they are 0 should work. If you have a special requirement to include them, you may use

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatterForXml
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx");
    System.out.println(date.format(formatterForXml));
```

This time the output is

```
2018-06-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
```

So exactly as from `date.toXMLFormat()` before. It’s also possible that you only need the date without time-of-day and UTC offset. If so, it still simpler:

```
    System.out.println(invReceivedDate.toString());
```

Output:

```
2018-06-30
```

**Why?** Not just because it works. `java.sql.Date` is long outdated and poorly designed, so don’t use it. Instead I am using `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The modern API is so much nicer to work with.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.