# Convert GregorianCalendar to XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

While working with legacy code not yet updated for the modern *java.time* classes, I need to convert a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html). So I thought I'd go by way of [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html), calling [`GregorianCalendar.from( ZonedDateTime )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#from(java.time.ZonedDateTime)).

I see methods for going from `XMLGregorianCalendar` to `GregorianCalendar`: [`XMLGregorianCalendar::toGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#toGregorianCalendar()).

➥ I need the opposite, going from `GregorianCalendar` to `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

Comment: Basil, this seems to be answered at https://stackoverflow.com/q/835889/ .  Any reason I shouldn't close this as duplicate?

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica Not a duplicate. A `java.util.Date` is not a `GregorianCalendar`. A `Date` is always in UTC, while a `GregorianCalendar` has a time zone. But I notice there is a kernel of an Answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56313273/642706) for here. I'll write an Answer now.

Comment: Sasuke's answer on that other question seems to be just what you wanted.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica Well, yes indeed, I see that one now. Ironically, [that Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/835983/642706) is *not* a correct answer on  [that Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/835889/642706) but is to mine here. So, again, this Question here is *not* a duplicate of [that Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/835889/642706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar( … )`

While neither the `XMLGregorianCalendar` nor `GregorianCalendar` classes offer the conversion method you need, there is a workaround.

A [`javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html) object can convert from `GregorianCalendar` to `XMLGregorianCalendar` by calling its [`newXMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newXMLGregorianCalendar(java.util.GregorianCalendar)) method.

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregCal = 
        DatatypeFactory
        .newInstance()
        .newXMLGregorianCalendar( gregCal ) 
;
```

---

To complete the entire cascade you mentioned, from `java.time.ZonedDateTime` to `GregorianCalendar` to `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregCal = 
        DatatypeFactory
        .newInstance()
        .newXMLGregorianCalendar( 
            GregorianCalendar
            .from(
                myZonedDateTime
            )
        ) 
;
```

Comment: Shouldn't people use the solution mentioned here instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62659961/6762888 which skips creating a newInstance() of DataTypeFactory which is expensive?

Comment: @A.D No, we should *not* use the `XMLGregorianCalendarImpl` class seen in [that Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62659961/642706). There is no such class listed in the [Javadoc for the public API of Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/index.html). The public API provides [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk19/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) but not `XMLGregorianCalendarImpl`. That class in an internal implementation detail, subject to change or removal.

Comment: @A.D Furthermore, [the Javadoc](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk19/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#%3Cinit%3E()) tells us explicitly to "Always use the `DatatypeFactory` to construct an instance of `XMLGregorianCalendar`".

Comment: Thanks! I ran into a performance issue with DatatypeFactory.newInstance() when we migrated from java 7 -> 8. I fixed it by caching the instance instead of creating one every time and hence the reason for my comment. But what you said is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is the following:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl;
    

GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = new XMLGregorianCalendarImpl(calendar);
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Javadoc for the `XMLGregorianCalendarImpl` class you use here?