# How to achive this date format in calendar

Tags: java, date, calendar, date-format, xmlgregoriancalendar

I have to create the XMLGregorianCalendar object with this date format "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS±TZ" e.g. "2015-07-01T17:42:49+04"

I have no idea how to do this. I've used a number of ways on how to convert date, but this pattern doesn't seem to work.

After some experiments I found that "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX" will give me the desired output. But it's a string and I can't achieve the same format with XMLGregorianCalendar.

It gives me "2015-07-01T17:42:4234+05:00", as you see there're additional symbols that i don't need.

Comment: Try and remember, a `Date` object (including `Calendar`) are just contains for the amount of time which has passed since a anchor point (ie the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch), they don't carry a concept of formatting, outside of "general human readable representation", which isn't really meant for much else then debugging.  Instead, you use a `DateFormatter` of some kind.  You will need to convert the `Calendar` to the appropriate object type that formatter expects, but that shouldn't be that hard

Comment: Did you mean that last piece of quoted text to include `+04:00` rather than `+05:00` to match the first paragraph?

Comment: I hope (and suspect) that you’re mistaken. (1) As @BasilBourque says in his answer, you shouldn’t need an `XMLGregorianCalendar`. (2) The format with offset in hours without minutes, `+04`, is not valid in XML. Therefore `XMLGregorianCalendar` cannot produce it. *An optional time zone expression may be added at the end of the value. The letter `Z` is used to indicate Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). All other time zones are represented by their difference from Coordinated Universal Time in the format `+hh:mm`, or `-hh:mm.`* [xsd:dateTime](http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_dateTime.html)

Comment: One simple way to see that you are asking the impossible is `DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2015-07-01T17:42:49+04")`. This throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2015-07-01T17:42:49+04`. `newXMLGregorianCalendar(String)` accepts all formats that `XMLGregorianCalendar` is capable of printing back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Date-time objects have no format

> XMLGregorianCalendar object with this date format

Date-time objects such as [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) do not have a “format”. They internally represent the date-time value in some manner, though not likely to be in text.

You can instantiate date-time objects by *parsing* text. And your date-time objects can *generate* text representing their internal value. But the text and the date-time object are distinct and separate from one another.

## *java.time*

The `XMLGregorianCalendar` class is now obsolete. Supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Parse your input string as a `OffsetDateTime` as in includes an offset-from-UTC but not a time zone.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2015-07-01T17:42:49+04" );
```

Generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = odt.toString() ;  // Generates text in ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2015-07-01T17:42:49+04:00

### Parts of an offset

The part at the end is the offset-from-UTC, a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the prime meridian. In ISO 8601, the Plus sign is a positive number that means *ahead* of UTC. A Minus sign is a negative number that means *behind* UTC.

### Suppressing parts of an offset

Some people may drop the seconds when zero, or drop the minutes when zero. But suppressing those digits does not change the meaning. These three strings all represent the very same moment:

- `2015-07-01T17:42:49+04`
- `2015-07-01T17:42:49+04:00`
- `2015-07-01T17:42:49+04:00:00`

You said:

> "2015-07-01T17:42:4234+05:00", as you see there're additional symbols that i don't need.

[I assume you really meant `"2015-07-01T17:42:49+04:00"` but made typos.]

You really should not care about this. Indeed, I recommend you always include both the hours and the minutes as I have seen multiple libraries/protocols that expect both hours and minutes, breaking if omitted. While the minutes and seconds are indeed optional in ISO 8601 when their value is zero, I suggest you always include the minutes when zero.

### `DateTimeFormatter`

If you insist otherwise, you will need to use `DateTimeFormatter` class, and possibly `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, to suppress the minutes when zero. Perhaps this:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssx" );
String output = odt.format( f );
```

> 2015-07-01T17:42:49+04

The `x` code in that formatting pattern suppressed the minutes, and seconds, if their value is zero.

If doing your own formatting, be sure to not truncate when non-zero, or your result will be a falsehood (a different moment). Take for example, representing this moment as seen in India where current the offset in use is five and half hours (an offset that includes 30 minutes rather than zero).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z );
OffsetDateTime odtKolkata = zdt.toOffsetDateTime();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "odtKolkata = " + odtKolkata );
```

> 2015-07-01T19:12:49+05:30

### `XMLGregorianCalendar`

If you absolutely must use the old legacy class `XMLGregorianCalendar`, you can create one from the ISO 8601 output of our `OffsetDateTime` object seen in code above. See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56313273/642706) on another Question.

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = null;
try
{
    xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar( odt.toString() );
}
catch ( DatatypeConfigurationException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println( "xgc.toString(): " + xgc );
```

> xgc.toString(): 2015-07-01T17:42:49+04:00

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).